# Property value changes in ViewModel before it is updated in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-livedata

What I have is a ViewModel, a Fragment and a RecyclerViewAdapter.
The use case is as follows:

1. User wants to change the name of one item in the RecyclerView.
2. His command is sent to the ViewModel.
3. ViewModel updates the item and postValue using LiveData
4. Fragment observes on the live property and sends a command to the RecyclerViewAdapter to update the list.
5. List is updated.

Snippet containing only methods that I checked are valid for this problem.

```
data class Name(
    var firstName: String = "",
    var lastName: String = "",
)

class NameListRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NameListRecyclerViewAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {
    private var names: List<Name> = listOf()

    fun setData(newList: List<Name>) {
        names = newList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

class NameListViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var names: MutableList<Name>? = null

    private val _nameList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Name>>()
    val nameList: LiveData<MutableList<Name>>
        get() = _nameList

    fun changeFirstName(index: Int, name: String) {
        names?.get(0)?.firstName = name  // in this very moment the names property in NameListRecyclerViewAdapter is being changed
        _nameList.postValue(names)
    }
}

class NamesListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: NameListViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: NameListRecyclerViewAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(
        view: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            requireActivity(),
            NameListViewModelFactory(requireActivity().applicationContext)
        ).get(NameListViewModel::class.java)

        recyclerViewAdapter = NameListRecyclerViewAdapter()
        recycler_view_layout.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(context).apply {
                    orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
                }
            adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
        }

        viewModel.nameList.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer {
                val result = it ?: return@Observer
                recyclerViewAdapter.setData(result)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

For the first time, the name is changing as it should, but the second one is very peculiar.
The name (the property in the RecyclerViewAdapter) is updated not when it should (in step 5) but in step 3 - even before the new value is posted using liveData.
My theory is that its the same list in the ViewModel and the RecyclerViewAdapter, but I have no idea why is that, why one is not a copy of the other??

**Update** The problem seems to be solved when in the ViewModel i add .toMutableList() as follows:

```
class NameListViewModel : ViewModel() {

    //...

    fun changeFirstName(index: Int, name: String) {
        names?.get(0)?.firstName = name
        _nameList.postValue(names.toMutableList()) // instead of simple _nameList.postValue(names)
    }
}
```

Does that mean that live data property has the exact same list and I have to make sure to copy it always?

Comment: Are you using databinding with Observable to notify the UI?

Comment: I am using databinding on the recyclerView items but it's non Observable data binding (I bind the Name class instance to appropiate textViews but they are updated as they should, after notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: but it was updating without the notify call right?

Comment: well, the binding itself is inside the viewholder so to update it I has to be bond again so I need the notifyDatasetChanged() to rebind it, if that is what you mean